# How to get "previous" url param in angular?

Tags: angular

I have a Routes constant as below and I need to get a configurationId param in ngOnInit inside the MachineGroupComponent. this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('configurationId') returns null.

How can I do it?

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ConfigurationsComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        component: ConfigurationsListComponent
      },
      {
        path: ':configurationId',
        component: ConfigurationComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: MachineGroupsComponent
          },
          {
            path: ':machineGroupId',
            component: MachineGroupComponent
          },
        ]
      },
    ]
  },

];
```

Comment: I'm not sure but following might help you -https://angular-training-guide.rangle.io/routing/child_routes

Answer (score 1):

to get the param value you can use ActivatedRoute

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    let param = params['yourParam'];
    console.log(param); 
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, add `paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always'` on your `app-routing.module.ts` and you'll be able to get the previous router params normally.

Like this:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes), RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always'
})],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
```

You have the documentation [here](https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#paramsInheritanceStrategy) in case you want to read more about.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```ts
ngOnInit() {
    // Get parent ActivatedRoute (this.route) of this route.
    this.route.parent.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
        this.configurationId = +params["configurationId"];
    });
}
```

Comment: Property 'parent' does not exist on type 'RouterState'

Comment: updated answer.
try this: this.route.parent.params.forEach(() => {}).

Answer (score 0):

We can traverse activatedRoute to get parent params

**Try this**

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.root.firstChild.root.firstChild.firstChild.paramMap.subscribe(
      (params) => {
        console.log(params.get('configurationId'));
      }
    );
  }
```